# Is mongo collection with only one element is stupid?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I need to list on my blog homepage one quite recent comment, the top author and 10 last articles (resume and authors list).

I think, instead of make multiple request in mongo database to get all the documents, I can just have a document containing all that data. Something like that :

```
{
    topAuthor: "",
    lastArticles: [{resume: "", authors: ["", ""]}...],
    lastComment: { user:"", content:"" }
}
```

I can update this document each time somebody post an article or when a user post a new comment if last comment is here since at least 1 hour. So there is no update intensive.

But the problem is that I only need one document like that. So, is it stupid to create a collection with just 1 document store inside ?

And sorry for my bad english, I'm french.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if that document is the result of some query, you are implementing your own query cache this way.

I would have a look at this question about MongoDB and query caching:

- [Caching repeating query results in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243588/caching-repeating-query-results-in-mongodb)

And if you stick that doc in its own collection or keep it among other docs in another collection is a matter of convenience.